# git move uncommited changes from master to new branch

Tags: git, github

There are solutions to similar problems in stackoverflow.
But I wanted to make sure my question falls in the same category:
I did a `git checkout master`

I made some changes(uncommitted) and realized that the changes should be made by creating a new branch instead of master.

Is there a command where I can move the changes to a new branch and revert the master in my local branch to the state it was before I made those changes?

Comment: A comment rather than an answer, since there could be a better way... but "git stash" will store your changes and restore your modified files; then change to the new branch, then "git stash pop" will apply the stored changes and remove the change from the stash stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't commit anything to master, there is nothing to "revert". Juste create a new branch with `git checkout -b new_branch` and commit your changes.

Comment: Additionally, I would need to to do a git pull from master. merge my master with my that specific branch and then push it to master. Would that affect anything?

Comment: You don't merge two branches together, you merge a branch into another. Your sentence is ambiguous, but I think you meant "merge my master into that specific branch and then merge the result back into master". And yes, it should affect both branches, why?